# Get Ienumrable type response from Genric Handler in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, handler

I am using a genric handler. Its returning the Ienumerable type Data but when i am getting the response from Handler i am unable to get . It gives an error when i am going to perform any operation on that data. I think i am not taking the response in a proper way. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Here is my Handler.

```
  public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    IUserInfosRepository _userRepo;
    public Handler1()
    {
        this._userRepo = new UserInfosRepository();
    }
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var Suppliers = GetData(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Active"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Inactive"].ToString()));
        //string name = context.Request.QueryString["name"];
        context.Response.Write(Suppliers);

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<UserInfoModel> GetData(int Active , int InactiveStatus)
    {
        var objUI = _userRepo.GetAllMembersWithDelete(Active, Active);
        return objUI;
    }

}
```

Here is my controller as i am using MVC

```
   string HandlerUrl = "http://localhost:8897/Handler1.ashx?Active=" + Status.Active + "&Inactive=" + Status.Inactive + "";
                var response = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(HandlerUrl);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8897/Handler1.ashx?Active=" + Status.Active + "&Inactive=" + Status.Inactive + "");
                HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var SearchDate = response.Where(x => x.LastLogin != null).GroupBy(x => x.LastLogin.Value.Date).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Select(x => new { LastLogin = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", x.Key) }).ToList();
```

Comment: " I gives an error" What is this error?

Comment: actually it was like it gives an error . its a kind of typing mistake.